# Switching tabs so they jump to top of page

Tags: html, tabs

What if my scroll changing tab html is just as following :

```
<a class="cute" onClick="document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=document.getElementById('others').innerHTML" title="OTHERS">OTHERS[/a>
```

And

```
<div id="others" style="display:none;">
```

For example, if you go to my blog @ http://shoppers-insane.blogspot.sg/ and click on "instocks" then scroll down to press, lets say, dresses, it wouldn't go up to the top after switching links!

Please help!

Comment: So do you want the web browser to autoscroll to a specific place on the new web page that is in the new tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the page from scrolling when an element is clicked you need to return false using the jQuery click handler to prevent the default action from happening:

```
<a href="#" id="test1">Do something!</a>
```

Then with jQuery:

```
$('#test1').click(function(e) {
     return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
     e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
});
```

If you want the page to scroll to a particular element on click all you need to do is set the anchor as the id of the element you want to scroll to.

```
<a href="#test1">Go to #test1 div</a>

<div id="test1"></div>
```